# C++ error while trying to assign std::string to hwProfileInfo

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
string hwid;

void getHWID()
{
    if (GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo))
    {
        hwid = hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid; 
    }
}
```

I know that the solution might me easy but I've been trying to fix this for a day now and it's pretty frustrating. I got a source from the internet with same method and it's working but whenever I try to use it for another project this error pops up:

> no operator matches these operands operand types are: std::string =
> WCHAR [39]

Can someone help me?

Comment: `WCHAR` is a 16-bit char (`wchar_t`). You can use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Or you can call the multi-byte version: `GetCurrentHwProfileA`. You should probably read up on MS wide string (unicode) vs multi-byte compiler options.